# how to add animation right to left using css or bootstrap on mouse hover?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3. I want something like, mouse hover on section area,  a particular div(Here from my code ABC) should be appear with right to left animation and disappear on mouse remove. I did it but without animation. How to add animation ? Please help me if any one has any idea. I have created bootply, You can see [here](http://www.bootply.com/PTgHapKmv3)

Link: http://www.bootply.com/PTgHapKmv3

My Codes are Below:

**HTML**

```
<section id="top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">                   
            <div class="col-sm-6">                        
                <h1><strong>CONNECTING</strong></h1>
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="fostering">
            <div class="row pad-top4" id="fostering">                
                    <h3>ABC</h3>                
            </div>  
          </div>
       </div>
   </div> 
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#top {
background: yellow;
  height:200px;
}
#fostering {
  display: none;
}
#top:hover #fostering {
  display: block;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help:

CSS

```
#fostering {
  display: none;
}

#fostering h3{
  margin-right:0px;
}

#top:hover #fostering {
  display: block;    
}

#top:hover #fostering h3{
   margin-right:100px; 
   transition:2s;
   -webkit-transition:2s;
   -moz-transition:2s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But its not working. Can you please add it to my code if possible?